# Regex - Skip characters to match

Tags: regex

I'm having an issue with Regex.

I'm trying to match `T0000001` (`2`, `3` and so on).

However, some of the lines it searches has what I can describe as positioners. These are shown as a question mark, followed by 2 digits, such as `?21`.
These positioners describe a new position if the document were to be printed off the website.

Example:

```
T123?214567
T?211234567
```

I need to disregard `?21` and match `T1234567`.

From what I can see, this is not possible.
I have looked everywhere and tried numerous attempts.

All we have to work off is the linked image. The creators cant even confirm the flavour of Regex it is - they believe its Python but I'm unsure.

[Regex Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R20wv.png)

#### Update

Unfortunately none of the codes below have worked so far. I thought to test each code in live (Rather than via regex thinking may work different but unfortunately still didn't work)

There is no replace feature, and as mentioned before I'm not sure if it is Python. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `T((\?21)?\d)+` might work, but it will greedily take any numbers after `T` that are not part of `?21`

Comment: Does [`^(T\d*)\?\d{2}(\d*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/6Bzg52/1) work for you?

Comment: `T[0-9]{7}|T[0-9(\?\d\d)]{10}`

Comment: Positive look-behind is your friend. Something like: `T\d*(?<=\?\d{2})\d+`

Comment: Thanks for the replies; in my example t01?2123456
each of the above 4 examples all return the example text apart from the last one which returns no match

Comment: @Shaine321 do you need to extract the number, eg `1234567` or do you just need to match?

Comment: @Innocent Bystander- I require it to find a match of T1234567

Answer (score 1):

Do two regex operations

First do the regex replace to replace the positioners with an empty string.

```
(\?[0-9]{2})
```

Then do the regex match

```
T[0-9]{7}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one occurrence of the 'positioners' in each match, something like this should work: `(T.*?)\?\d{2}(.*)`

This can be tested here: https://regex101.com/r/XhQXkh/2

Basically, match two capture groups before and after the '?21' sequence. You'll need to concatenate these two matches.

Comment: In the link you provide, it works perfect however in my earlier example and image, there is no option for substitution. I need the expression all in one line. Really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

At first, match the `?21` and repace it with a distinctive character, `@`, etc

```
\?21
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/20/)

and you may try this regex to find what you want

```
(T(?:\d{7}|[\@\d]{8}))\s
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/21/),,, in which target string is captured to `group 1` (or `\1`).

Finally, replace `@` with `?21` or something you like.

Python script may be like this

```
ss="""T123?214567
T?211234567
T1234567
T1234434?21
T5435433"""

rexpre= re.compile(r'\?21')
regx= re.compile(r'(T(?:\d{7}|[\@\d]{8}))\s')
for m in regx.findall(rexpre.sub('@',ss)):
    print(m)
print()
for m in regx.findall(rexpre.sub('@',ss)):
    print(re.sub('@',r'?21', m))
```

Output is

```
T123@4567
T@1234567
T1234567
T1234434@

T123?214567
T?211234567
T1234567
T1234434?21
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a replace functionality is an option for you then this might be an approach to match `T0000001` or `T123?214567`:

- Capture a `T` followed by zero or more digits before the optional part in group 1 `(T\d*)`
- Make the question mark followed by 2 digits part optional `(?:\?\d{2})?`
- Capture one or more digits after in group 2 `(\d+)`.

Then in the replacement you could use group1group2 `\1\2`.

Using word boundaries `\b` *(Or use assertions for the start and the end of the line `^` `$`)* this could look like:

[`\b(T\d*)(?:\?\d{2})?(\d+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/PXLTNT/1/)

[Example Python](http://rextester.com/GYMM3553)

Answer (score 0):

Is the below what you want?

```
Use RegExReplace with multiline tag (m) and enable replace all occurrences!
Pattern = (T\d*)\?\d{2}(\d*)
replace = $1$2
```

*Usage Example:*

[image: Example 1]

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, unfortunately as mentioned there is no replace option built into the regex.